# Finding rejection region for an exact one-sample binomial test.

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

Can $n=10$ be used? $n=20?$ $n=25?$ What is the appropriate rejection region for the chosen $n,$ and what are the actual error probabilities when this region is used?
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a copy-pasted homework question. (Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences, Jay Devore, Exercise 8.3.45 of the 8th edition) Can you please edit by adding your own thoughts and progress?

Comment: Can we please focus on one part of one problem at a time? And with some guidance exactly why you are having difficulty?

Comment: You have been a registered user on this site for less than 3 weeks, have asked about two dozen questions, and in nearly all cases, you fail to show any effort on your part.  You expect others to spend considerable effort to answer lengthy homework questions but you don't seem to want to put in your own effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a partial outline to get you started:

Let $X$ be the number of leaky faucets observed out of $n.$
The null hypothesis is $H_0: p = .1$ and alternative is $H_a: p > .1.$
'Not proceed' means $H_0$ is rejected.

We seek $\alpha = P(\text{Rej}\, |\, p=.1) \le .1$ and $\beta(.3) = 
P(\text{Fail to Rej}\, |\, p=.3) \le .1.$ Try $n = 25$ and see what happens.

**Finding rejection region for specified significance level.**

If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=25, p=.1),$ then $P(X \ge 5) = .0980 < 0.1,$
so we use rejection region $\{5, 6, \dots, 25\}.$ (Computations use R statistical software, where `dbinom` is a binomial PDF and `5:20` is the rejection region.)

```
sum(dbinom(4:20, 25, .1))
[1] 0.2364086
sum(dbinom(5:20, 25, .1))
[1] 0.09799362
```

**Finding Type II error for a specified rejection region.**

If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 25, p=.3),$ then $P(X \le 4) = .0904 < 0.1.$ 
So using $n = 25$ and rejection region $\{5, 6, \dots, 25\}$ seems to work.

```
sum(dbinom(0:4, 25, .3))
[1] 0.09047192
```

It seems that the first image in your Question is an answer to this problem
or a similar one (the disagreement in question numbers notwithstanding).
I will leave it to you to explain why the other values $n = 10$ and $n = 20$
won't work, and why for $n = 25$ we need to use rejection region $\{5, 6, \dots, 25\}.$

---

In the figure below, blue bars represent the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(25,.1)$ and 
red bars represent the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(25,.3).$  The rejection region is
to the right of the vertical dotted line.

[image]